# Deploying SharePoint 2013 on a Single Server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a fairly small SharePoint deployment (it will be used by at most 20 or so people).  What are the pitfalls of using the single server setup that is offered by 2013?  The installer says to avoid using it in a production environment - but will I be able to get away with it if the server that I am deploying to has enough hardware to run SQL and SharePoint on the same machine?  Or are there some services which cannot be used with that type of deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can deploy the SharePoint as single server farm which is also called Limited Deployment. This type of deployment is good for Less then 100 users.

> Limited deployments are typically  used for product evaluation, 
>   development and testing, or for  environments that have limited 
>   numbers of users and don t require  fault-tolerance.

You should install it as Single Server Farm, so that in future you can scale out if needed. Only enable those services which need and shut all other services down. Hope fully the same server is not used for Domain Controller. You also keep in mind that only option in disaster recover will be totally build the farm.

Check this topology. http://zoom.it/AgjL#full
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=257304
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=286978

Answer (score 1):

A single server installation consists of one server that runs both SQL Server and SharePoint 2013. You can install and configure SharePoint 2013 on a single server if you are hosting only a few sites for a limited number of users or if you want to create a trial or development environment. This configuration is also useful if you want to configure a farm to meet your needs first, and then add servers to the farm at a later stage.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262243(v=office.15).aspx#section1

You can start by using a single server setup and as it evolves you can add new servers to the farm.

If you read the msdn article, Microsoft is supporting such a setup. But you need to fine tune what all services you should configure. For example Search, BCS etc.

[Minimum real world system requirements for SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58370/minimum-real-world-system-requirements-for-sharepoint-2013)