# Minimum Setup for Word Automation Services on Sharepoint Server 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, word-automation, document-converter

I am attempting to build a on demand word (and excel later) converter to PDF. All my searching has led me to believe the best server-side option would be Word Automation Services. (Let me know if this is incorrect). This does need to be a server side solution.

I am trying to learn how to setup a Sharepoint Server 2013. There are a lot of moving parts, but I want to know what the minimum requirements would be for such a system. I would like to do some development. I am planning on getting an azure sharepoint server farm, but would like to test it out on a VM initially.

I came across this article: [Minimum real world system requirements for SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58370/minimum-real-world-system-requirements-for-sharepoint-2013). I wanted any help on hints on anything extra I could eliminate.

The sole purpose of this system will be to handle upload of office files (.docx, .doc, .xlsx, .xls) and convert them to pdf. It will also had to provide log and maybe send out alerts, but that is all.

Answer (score 0):

Minimum requirement depend upon the company's requirement.

- Number of User will use this farm
- what type of service will be used in farm( i.e Word, search, UPA etc)
- Purpose of the Usage i.e collaboration or portal
- concurrent users
- High availability.

From your questions, looks like the main purpose just for conversion, So you need 2 WFE, 2 APP servers and 1 SQL server. this will give you high availability farm.

You can check the Mini Hardware requirement of a server  from Techent:

[Hardware and software requirements for SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx#hwforwebserver)

[Streamlined Topology](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30377)