# How to proceed for Installation of SharePoint Server 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server, windows-server

Can someone please guide me through installation of SharePoint server 2013? I am absolutely new to this installation and don't have any networking and programming knowledge. I went through the Microsoft website but it confused me a lot about minimum requirements.

My desktop Configuration is:
(OS: Windows 8.1 Pro - 64 Bit)
(RAM - 8 GB)
(Processor - Intel Core i7 - 3.4 GHz - x64-based processor)

Please tell me how to install it and about prerequisites needed to install this. I want to install it as a server which will be be used to create a website for project monitoring dashboard. I have not installed anything like SQL Server, Windows Server, .Net etc. Please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure SharePoint 2013 on-premises is the right tool for you? It takes quite some experience to support a SharePoint server installation in terms of installation, patching, backup/restore, troubleshooting, etc. I would not recommend your choice given you have no experience with the product. Have you considered a SharePoint Online site in Office 365?

Comment: @LarsFastrup Through MSDN Subscription of my college, I could get SharePoint Server. I am not able to get SharePoint online subscription. As it is part of my Masters Degree Project, I can not buy SharePoint online subscription. For providing proof of my conceptual design of project monitoring system, I am considering SharePoint Server. Can you suggest any other alternative?

Comment: Ok - a student project - now I'm less worried! What problem does your system aim to solve? Not sure what to suggest or recommend at this point.

Comment: @lars my main objective is to design a dashboard which will contain all projects. I can access all the projects. So for every project tasks will be assigned with expected deadlines. Live tracking should be achievable through this. Also document sharing should be made possible within the team.

Comment: Thanks for the added details - SharePoint may indeed be a good choice here! I assume you'll be using the Tasks list to track project tasks and deadlines?

Comment: Yes.. Tasks will be entered using task list for tracking..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant install SP2013 on Windows 8.1 OS, you need to have either of the below as OS

1. Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, 64 bit
2. Windows Server 2012, 64 bit
3. Windows Server 2012 R2, 64 bit (requires SharePoint 2013 with SP1)

You also need either of the below version of SQL server

1. SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1, 64 bit
2. SQL Server 2012, 64 bit

After that , you can take a look at the fantastic [AutoSPIntaller](https://autospinstaller.com/) which allows to to do scripted farm environment creation . You can create an XML file on the site itself and then run the `AutoSPInstaller.bat` which will create the environment for you.

Reference - [Hardware and software requirements for SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx)

Comment: can i install Windows Server 2012 Datacenter 64-bit (English) and SQL server 2012 express 64 bit. through MSDN I can download and install these both. Will it be suffiicient? I have downloaded SharePoint Server 2013 64-bit (English). I don't know its service pack version.

Comment: You do not need Windows Server Datacenter Edition (that one has more features than the normal one). SQL Server will work. I recommend using a virtual machine

Comment: @Nils thanks. I am completely newbie here. I hope you don't get irritated by the questions. Will you please tell me what is virtual machine? Can I install SQL Server 2012 and SharePoint server 2013 without even looking for Windows Server 2012?  or Do i need to install windows server 2012?

Comment: @RonakD Virtual Machine is ann software where you can install the OS and everything (You mentioned in the above comment) like your machine!

Comment: I used virtual box to install Windows Server 2012 R2. It is having a different IP address than my Windows 8.1 OS. Will it work for my purpose? and where should i install sharepoint and sql? in windows server 2012 (through virtual box) or in windows 8.1 Pro?

Comment: Yes thats the correct approach. Virtual box is ok. Hyper-V is also good. So yes, it will work for your purposes

Comment: @GautamSheth Thanks. where should i install sharepoint and sql? in windows server 2012 (through virtual box) or in windows 8.1 Pro?

Comment: @RonakD - install both in the virtual box windows server 2012

Comment: Okay. But for installation of Windowa Server through Virtual Box I allocated 3 Gb of ram and 30 GB of space. Will it be enough to run Sharepoint and sql if i install it in the virtual box?

Comment: Mate, please go through the links provided in my answer as well the the one by Jack. 3 GB RAM is not enough, you need 8GB ram and 80 GB space for development purposes.

Comment: @GautamSheth Okay. I Will again install the Windows server 2012 by allocating required RAM and Hard disk specifications. Will you recommend dual booting (Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012) instead of booting Windows server through Virtual box?

Comment: I dont see the need to dual boot , but its completely your choice :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Guys. I have installed SharePoint Server 2013 on Windows Server 2012. Now I am facing the different issue. I am unable to access to my SharePoint Site through Browser. I have posted the new question about it. Thanks a lot for your help to get this installation done. The Url for new question is: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/206029/proxy-could-not-meet-destination-server-in-time-mcafee-for-sharepoint-site

Answer (score 3):

Look at this post concerning SharePoint 2013 requirements : [Minimum real world requirements for SP2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58370/minimum-real-world-system-requirements-for-sharepoint-2013)

You should go for Windows Server 2008 R2 + SQL Server 2008 R2 that are a bit lighter than the 2012 versions.

Concerning the Virtual Machine, I recommend you to use [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)

Comment: Thanks a lot..!! That link cleared many of the doubts. :)